# Why ubuntu doesn't see wi-fi card?

Tags: wireless, hardware

I have installed  ubuntu server and when installing, there was wi-fi card aviable and I connected with it. After installation, there is no wi-fi card seen by ubuntu. What can I do? Card is from TP-Link

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180